# The following error occurred when I was using AutoMapper

Tags: automapper

Development environment:

AutoMapper：7.0.1
NetCore:2.1

Wrong content:
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters

My Model:

```
public partial class XsOrdersitems
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ParentNo { get; set; }
        public string GoodsSn { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Barcode { get; set; }
    }
```

My DTO type：

```
public class DTOOrderItem
    {
        public string OrderPaNo { get; set; }
        public string OrderNo { get; set; }
        public string OrderNe { get; set; }
        public string OrderComm { get; set; }
    }
```

My mapping configuration：

```
reateMap<DTOOrderItem, XsSalesitems>()
     .ForMember(d => d.Id, opt =>opt.Ignore())
     .ForMember(d => d.Name, opt => { opt.MapFrom(s => s.OrderNe); })
     .ForMember(d => d.GoodsSn, opt => { opt.MapFrom(s => s.OrderNo);})          
     .ForMember(d => d.ParentNo, opt => { opt.MapFrom(s =>s.OrderPaNo);})
     .ForMember(d => d.Comment, opt => { opt.MapFrom(s => s.OrderComm); });
```

I tried to use opt. `Ignore()` to ignore the unconfigured mapping attributes, but still reported the above error, please help me, thank you for your time to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Per your examples you are mapping to the wrong model. Your `CreateMap` definition is mapping `DTOOrderItem` to `XsSalesitems`, but your comments suggest you are wanting to map to `XsOrderitems`. Might try adding an additional `CreateMap<DTOOrderItem, XsOrderitems>()...` with the necessary `.Ignore()` references and you should be good to go.

Complete mapping definition:

```
CreateMap<DTOOrderItem, XsOrderitems>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(d => d.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.OrderNe))
    .ForMember(d => d.GoodsSn, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.OrderNo))          
    .ForMember(d => d.ParentNo, opt => opt.MapFrom(s =>s.OrderPaNo))
    .ForMember(d => d.Comment, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.OrderComm));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm sorry I didn't realize the details. Thank you again for your answer.

Comment: No worries! If this fixed your problem would you mind accepting this as the answer?